# 2Dimentional Numpy array(NDarray) to C#: Linq Query returns limitations of Marshal.Copy error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, keras

I have implemented a ML model using keras in c#. The output is a 4dim vector.

I have the following predict function to predict one entry.

```
public (DateTime TimeStamp, double dim1, double dim2, double dim3, double dim4) Predict(ForecastControllPower input)
            => Predict(new List<ForecastControllPower>() { input }).First();
```

But I want to now return a whole IEnumerable of entries. So I also define the following function:

```
        public IEnumerable<(DateTime TimeStamp, double dim1, double dim2, double dim3, double dim4)> Predict(IEnumerable<ForecastControllPower> input)
        {
           var model = Sequential.LoadModel(MODEL_FILEPATH, compile: false);
           var data = TransformData(input);
           var prediction = model.Predict(data.x);
           return input.Zip(prediction.GetData<float[]>().ToList(), (inp, pred) => (inp.TimeStamp, (double)pred[0], (double)pred[1], (double)pred[2], (double)pred[3]));//this line gets the error
       }
```

The problem sits with the last Linq Query(shown in the code) where I want to return an IEnumerable with all the right parameters. The error I get is a runtime error that reads:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
 HResult=0x80131509
 Message=Can not copy the data with data type due to limitations of Marshal.Copy: Single[]
 Source=Numpy.Bare
 StackTrace:
  at Numpy.NDarray.GetData[T]()[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Below is a screenshot of the structure of the prediction variable.
[image]

Additionally, which I think the base of the problem, I can say that the following 2 lines returns the same exception.

```
 var m = np.array(new double[,] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}});//making a numpy array, this works
 var t = m.GetData<double[,]>();//trying to get it back into C#, this gives the exception
```

Comment: See : https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET#create-a-numpy-array-from-a-c-array-and-vice-versa

Comment: According to the link I should use roots.GetData<Datatype T>()). 

Because I have an array of 4 dimensional points returned I assume the data type of GetData<double[]> should be fine then?

Comment: Then you have either have an array of two dimension points (x,y) or three dimensions points (x,y,x).  If you have an array of a complex type it is an array of pointers.  Do you have a Point (integer) or PointF (floating point)?

Comment: Are you referring to the datatype of the output of the ML model? That would be a float.

Comment: You said "I have an array of 4 dimensional points".  What are the points you are referring to?  Do you have a one or two dimensional array?

Comment: My ML model is a Neural Network that has an output dimension of 4. Therefore the function model.Predict(data.x) will return an 2 dimentinal array of size NumRows x 4.

Comment: The error says "imitations of Marshal.Copy: Single[]"  So you have a two dimensional array in c++ but only a one dimensional array in c#.  The Marshal class in Net Library is the interface the takes the c# managed memory and converts to c++ unmanaged memory.

Comment: The way I understand is, that I need to copy it to Managed c# memory. (Since I am working in C#) ie. the opposite of a Marshall copy? But obviously I am completely misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes.  If you are returning data than same applies.  The c++ is a two dimensional array and c# is one dimensional.

Comment: Just the function prediction.GetData<double[]>().ToList() returns the same error(obviously), so to simplify, how would I access the datapoints?

Comment: Look at the Github link I provided under multidimensional arrays

Comment: `input.x` -- Does that even compile? Anyway, when using an `IEnumerable<T>` twice in a method it's good practice to make sure it executes only once. The second execution may not yield the same results as the first one. Not sure if this is related to your issue.

Comment: @GertArnold Edited the code, in the process of simplifying the code I accidentally took out an important(but irrelevant) part.

Comment: @jdweng I read that in detail, and it seems that what I have should almost work, and tried some more, but I just cant seem to get it. I added an image that shows the variable in detail

Comment: My link show : var m = np.array(new int[,] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}});  and your code has : GetData<float[]>  Note : float[] is a one dimensional array.  You need to create a two dimensional np array and then map to a one dimensional array.

Comment: var m = np.array(new int[,] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}});  makes an NDarray, simular to the "prediction" that I have. I am interested in getting the data from the NDarray "prediction" into a C# IEnumerable<(DateTime, double, double, double, double)>. Therefore I tried datatypes such as GetData<float[,]>  and GetData<float[][]>...etc

Comment: You need m.GetData<float[,]> where m is the result of np.array. the c++ size and c# size must match. Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Yes, with m.GetData<float[,]> I get the following: Can not copy the data with data type due to limitations of Marshal.Copy: Single[,]

Comment: even the following code gives the same exception at the second line
var m = np.array(new int[,] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}});
var t = m.GetData<int[,]>();

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can just call `.GetData<float>()` which will return 2D array flattened to 1D